# flask server running in virtual box is not accessible from the windows host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, flask, server, virtualbox

I have tried running it from host='0.0.0.0' and it is still inaccessible. I can ping my windows machine ip 192.168.1.109 from my virtualmachine, but I can not ping my Ubuntu VirtualMachine ip from ifconfig 10.0.2.15 from my windows side. I am using virtualbox if that helps.

run.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000, debug=True)
```

**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_babel import Babel, lazy_gettext
from config import basedir, ADMINS, MAIL_SERVER, MAIL_PORT, MAIL_USERNAME, \
    MAIL_PASSWORD
from .momentjs import momentjs

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'
lm.login_message = lazy_gettext('Please log in to access this page.')
mail = Mail(app)
babel = Babel(app)


class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    """This class adds support for lazy translation texts to Flask's
    JSON encoder. This is necessary when flashing translated texts."""
    def default(self, obj):
        from speaklater import is_lazy_string
        if is_lazy_string(obj):
            try:
                return unicode(obj)  # python 2
            except NameError:
                return str(obj)  # python 3
        return super(CustomJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)

app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder

if not app.debug and MAIL_SERVER != '':
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
    credentials = None
    if MAIL_USERNAME or MAIL_PASSWORD:
        credentials = (MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD)
    mail_handler = SMTPHandler((MAIL_SERVER, MAIL_PORT),
                               'no-reply@' + MAIL_SERVER, ADMINS,
                               'microblog failure', credentials)
    mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

if not app.debug and os.environ.get('HEROKU') is None:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('tmp/microblog.log', 'a',
                                       1 * 1024 * 1024, 10)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('microblog startup')

if os.environ.get('HEROKU') is not None:
    import logging
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    app.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('microblog startup')

app.jinja_env.globals['momentjs'] = momentjs

from app import views, models
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I changed this line in the main

```
app.run()
```

to

```
app.run(host='192.168.163.128', port=5000)
```

Comment: Which ip is that?